# Identify AD user account from Disconnect Exchange Mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

I've been trying to do this for a while now. When Exchange mailboxes are disabled or soft-deleted they are disconnected from their AD user account object. We can reconnect them if we want to but is there a way to identify the AD user account it was associated with before disconnect ?.

I'm not an on-prem Exchange Administrator but have the necessary access for Recipient Configuration.

I've been able to use the `displayName` property from `Get-MailboxStatistics` results, but `displayName` is not a unique attribute (like `distinguishedname`, for instance).

I'm connecting to Exchange Server 2013 via PowerShell remote PSSession.

- I know `LastLoggedOnUserAccount` property is no longer an option with 2013.
- I see Mailbox auditing can help but this needs to be enabled per mailbox, this is out of my work scope and might add a big overhead in large organizations
- `Search-MailboxAuditLog` cmdlet is not visible for me in PowerShell my Exchange Management session

Any solution/workaround would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this myself, but there is a property returned by `Get-MailboxStatistics` you could use, which is called `MailboxGuid`.

Below should get you a list of disconnected mailboxes where besides the DisplayName, the users EmailAddress and DistinghuishedName is returned.

```
Get-MailboxStatistics | Where-Object { $_.DisconnectReason } | ForEach-Object {   # get disconected mailboxes
    $email  = Get-User -Identity $_.MailboxGuid.Guid | Select-Object -ExpandProperty WindowsEmailAddress
    $userDN = Get-Mailbox -Identity $email | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
    Select-Object DisconnectDate, DisconnectReason, DisplayName, 
                  @{Name = "EmailAddress"; Expression = { $email }},
                  @{Name = "DistinguishedName"; Expression = {$userDN }}
}
```